# No sound on medion akoya e2221t on ubuntu 21.10

Tags: sound, alsa, 21.10

It worked on 20.04, which had the module "snd_soc_sst_cht_bsw_nau8824" in the section "Loaded ALSA modules" and "chtnau8824" in "Soundcards recognised by ALSA".

Difference between ubuntu versions:

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks a lot.

That below is my alsa-info:

```
upload=true&script=true&cardinfo=
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.65
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Wed Feb  2 18:06:33 UTC 2022


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 21.10 \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 21.10" PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 21.10" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy" UBUNTU_CODENAME=impish


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      MEDION
Product Name:      E2221T MD60691
Product Version:   AMIC
Firmware Version:  5.11
System SKU:        ML-241005 30023022
Board Vendor:      MEDION
Board Name:        NT16H


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/10508824:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/80860F14:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/80860F14:02/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/80860F14:03/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/8086228A:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/8086228A:01/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/8086228E:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/8086228E:01/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/8086228E:02/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/808622A8:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/808622C1:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/808622C1:01/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/808622C1:02/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/808622C1:03/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/808622C1:04/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/808622C1:05/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/808622C1:06/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI0003:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI0011:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/FTSC1000:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33A4:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33D3:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33D5:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33F4:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33FE:01/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33FF:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33FF:01/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33FF:02/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33FF:03/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33FF:04/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3400:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3403:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3403:02/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3406:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTL9C60:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INTL9C60:01/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:00/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:01/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:02/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:08/status     2
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:09/status     2
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0a/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0b/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0c/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0d/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0e/status     2
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:0f/status     2
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:10/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:11/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:12/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:13/status     2
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:14/status     2
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:15/status     2
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:16/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:17/status     1
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:28/status     2
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXPOWER:29/status     2
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/MSFT0101:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0D:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:0c/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:1d/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:48/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:4c/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:51/status   15


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    5.13.0-28-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k5.13.0-28-generic
Library version:    1.2.4
Utilities version:  1.2.4


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_hdmi_lpe_audio


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [Audio          ]: HdmiLpeAudio - Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
                      Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------



!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Module: snd_hdmi_lpe_audio
    id : (null)
    index : -1
    single_port : N


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Feb  2 19:05 /dev/snd/controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Feb  2 19:06 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Feb  2 19:06 /dev/snd/pcmC0D1p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Feb  2 19:06 /dev/snd/pcmC0D2p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Feb  2 19:05 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Feb  2 19:05 /dev/snd/timer

/dev/snd/by-path:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  60 Feb  2 19:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 180 Feb  2 19:05 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Feb  2 19:05 pci-0000:00:02.0-platform-hdmi-lpe-audio -> ../controlC0


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 0: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audi]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 1: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audi]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 2: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audi]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

ARECORD

**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!-------Mixer controls for card Audio

Card hw:0 'Audio'/'Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio'
  Mixer name    : ''
  Components    : ''
  Controls      : 15
  Simple ctrls  : 0


!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

--startcollapse--
state.Audio {
    control.1 {
        iface PCM
        name 'IEC958 Playback Mask'
        value ffffffff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.2 {
        iface PCM
        name 'IEC958 Playback Default'
        value '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.3 {
        iface PCM
        name ELD
        value '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read volatile'
            type BYTES
            count 128
        }
    }
    control.4 {
        iface PCM
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        value.2 0
        value.3 0
        value.4 0
        value.5 0
        value.6 0
        value.7 0
        comment {
            access read
            type INTEGER
            count 8
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
    control.5 {
        iface CARD
        name 'HDMI/DP,pcm=0 Jack'
        value false
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.6 {
        iface PCM
        device 1
        name 'IEC958 Playback Mask'
        value ffffffff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.7 {
        iface PCM
        device 1
        name 'IEC958 Playback Default'
        value '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.8 {
        iface PCM
        device 1
        name ELD
        value '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read volatile'
            type BYTES
            count 128
        }
    }
    control.9 {
        iface PCM
        device 1
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 0
        value.1 0
        value.2 0
        value.3 0
        value.4 0
        value.5 0
        value.6 0
        value.7 0
        comment {
            access read
            type INTEGER
            count 8
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
    control.10 {
        iface CARD
        name 'HDMI/DP,pcm=1 Jack'
        value false
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.11 {
        iface PCM
        device 2
        name 'IEC958 Playback Mask'
        value ffffffff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
        comment {
            access read
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.12 {
        iface PCM
        device 2
        name 'IEC958 Playback Default'
        value '0482000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read write'
            type IEC958
            count 1
        }
    }
    control.13 {
        iface PCM
        device 2
        name ELD
        value '1000070067100001000000000000000022f6256a5a51452d4341410907070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
        comment {
            access 'read volatile'
            type BYTES
            count 128
        }
    }
    control.14 {
        iface PCM
        device 2
        name 'Playback Channel Map'
        value.0 3
        value.1 4
        value.2 0
        value.3 0
        value.4 0
        value.5 0
        value.6 0
        value.7 0
        comment {
            access read
            type INTEGER
            count 8
            range '0 - 36'
        }
    }
    control.15 {
        iface CARD
        name 'HDMI/DP,pcm=2 Jack'
        value true
        comment {
            access read
            type BOOLEAN
            count 1
        }
    }
}
--endcollapse--


!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

8250_dw
ac97_bus
acpi_pad
acpi_thermal_rel
aesni_intel
af_alg
algif_hash
algif_skcipher
atomisp
atomisp_gmin_platform
autofs4
axp20x
axp20x_i2c
axp20x_pek
axp288_adc
axp288_charger
axp288_fuel_gauge
bluetooth
bnep
btbcm
btintel
btrtl
btusb
ccm
cec
cfg80211
cmac
coretemp
crc32_pclmul
crct10dif_pclmul
cryptd
crypto_simd
drm
drm_kms_helper
dw_dmac
dw_dmac_core
ecc
ecdh_generic
efi_pstore
exfat
extcon_axp288
fb_sys_fops
ghash_clmulni_intel
gpio_keys
hid
hid_generic
hid_multitouch
i2c_algo_bit
i2c_hid
i2c_hid_acpi
i915
industrialio
industrialio_triggered_buffer
input_leds
int3400_thermal
int3403_thermal
int3406_thermal
int340x_thermal_zone
intel_cht_int33fe
intel_cstate
intel_hid
intel_int0002_vgpio
intel_powerclamp
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
intel_soc_dts_iosf
intel_xhci_usb_role_switch
ip_tables
iwlmvm
iwlwifi
joydev
kfifo_buf
kvm
kvm_intel
kxcjk_1013
ledtrig_audio
libarc4
lp
lpc_ich
mac80211
mac_hid
mc
mei
mei_hdcp
mei_txe
mmc_block
msr
nls_iso8859_1
parport
parport_pc
ppdev
processor_thermal_device
processor_thermal_mbox
processor_thermal_rapl
processor_thermal_rfim
punit_atom_debug
rc_core
rfcomm
sch_fq_codel
sdhci
sdhci_acpi
snd
snd_compress
snd_hdmi_lpe_audio
snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_intel_sdw_acpi
snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_intel_sst_core
snd_pcm
snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_rawmidi
snd_seq
snd_seq_device
snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event
snd_soc_acpi
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match
snd_soc_core
snd_soc_nau8824
snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform
snd_soc_sst_cht_bsw_nau8824
snd_sof
snd_sof_acpi
snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt
snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp
snd_timer
soc_button_array
soundcore
sparse_keymap
spi_pxa2xx_platform
syscopyarea
sysfillrect
sysimgblt
uas
usb_storage
usbhid
uvcvideo
video
videobuf2_common
videobuf2_memops
videobuf2_v4l2
videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf_core
videobuf_vmalloc
videodev
x_tables
xhci_pci
xhci_pci_renesas


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------



!!Packages installed
!!--------------------

ii  alsa-topology-conf                         1.2.5.1-2                                  all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                              1.2.4-2ubuntu5                             all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                 1.2.4-1ubuntu4                             amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues with a Medion 2228T. Try to download https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/archive/refs/heads/main.zip , unzip and install v1.9